# Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $T^2 = I$ and $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of T. Prove that $T = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification, linear-transformations

I was reading Axler's Linear Algebra Done Right, and the following appears as exercise $3$ in chapter $5$, section A:

> Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and $T^2 = I$ and $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of T. Prove that $T = I$

I try to prove it as follows:

Suppose $T \neq I$, and let $v \in V$ be such that:
$$Tv = -w \quad (1)$$,
for some $w \in V$.
Now apply $T$ to both sides gives us:
$$T(Tv) = -Tw$$
$$\implies T^2v = -Tw$$
$$\implies v = -Tw \quad (2)$$
Now lets use $(1)$ and $(2)$ as follows:
$$T(v + w) = Tv + Tw = -(v + w)$$
This implies that $-1$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, contradicting the assumption which completes the proof.

Is that correct?

**Note: I Do not ask for any other solutions please read the question carefully!**

#Edit:

To use $T \neq I$ and to prove that there $v, w \in V$ such that $v + w \neq 0$ and $Tv = -w$:

First if $Tv = 0$ then $v = 0$ otherwise we would have $T^2v = 0$ contradicting that $T^2 = I$.

So assume that $Tv \neq v$ for some $v \in V$ (i.e $T \neq I)$ and $Tv = -w$,
if $v + w = 0 \implies v = -w$ we have:

$$-Tw = Tv = -w$$
$$\implies Tw = w$$
$$\implies T(-v) = -v$$
$$\implies Tv = v$$
contradicting the assumption that $Tv \neq v$.

Comment: How do you know that you can find any such $v$ and $w$ such that (1) is true and $v + w \neq 0$? (Note that if $v + w = 0$, then you haven't proven that $-1$ is an eigenvalue)

Comment: @AlexG. Good point, I am trying to prove (or disprove) that, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Towards correcting it, note you haven't actually used $T\neq I$ anywhere, and $(1)$ isn't saying anything.  You should use $T\neq I$ to choose $v$ with a certain property...

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have edited the answer following your comment (and Alex comment), is it correct now?

Comment: It's a little wordy, but it seems fine now.  I should point out that your proof is essentially the contrapositive of copper.hat's.  [Try re-writing his with $x=v, Tx=-w$]

Answer (score 8):

Suppose $y=Tx-x$, then $Ty = -y$ and so we must have $y=0$. Hence $Tx=x$.

Comment: +1, short and sweet

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

$ T $  and $ T+I $ are bijective.

For any vector $ u\ne 0$,
$$(T+I)u\ne 0$$
and

$$(T-I)((T+I)u)=(T^2-I^2)u=0$$

Comment: It's perhaps more useful to switch $T - I$ and $T + I$: $(T + I)((T - I)v) = 0$ and $(T + I)v \neq 0$, both for all $v \neq 0$.

Comment: @AlexG. I proved $ (T-I)v=0$ for any $ v=(T+I)u$

Comment: I am not asking for other proofs, please read the question carefully.

Comment: @KaisHasan I did not assume $ T \ne I$ like you did.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah You have to mention in your proof that every $v$ can be expressed as $(T + I) u$ for some $u$. This is true because $T + I$ is invertible, but it takes an extra sentence just to point it out. Swapping the $T + I$ and $T - I$ avoids this.

Comment: @AlexG. T is invertible since $T^2=I$ and $ T^{-1}=T$.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this exercise as follows:

> Since $-1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$, $T+I$ is invertible by 5.6 on p.134 in "Linear Algebra Done Right 3rd Edition" by Sheldon Axler.
> Since $T^2=I$, $T^2-I=(T+I)(T-I)=0$.
> So, $T-I=(T+I)^{-1}(T+I)(T-I)=(T+I)^{-1}0=0$.
> So, $T=I$.